# Need to generate "to date" from 2 (or more) different "from dates"

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a cost table with id, price, and from date. I don't have a "to date". So item1 may have the price of £50 from 01/01/2019 in one row, then item1 will then have the price of £55 from 01/01/2020, in a second row.

If I want to know the price of item 1 today, I couldn't use `WHERE today >= fromdate and <= todate`.

How do I add "todate"? Where todate is the day before the next row's fromdate?

Ideally need to do this as view, want to avoid creating tables/stored proc, if possible?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at the [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function...

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <table> WHERE fromdate<=getdate() order by fromdate desc.

Answer (score 2):

To get today's price get the row with the latest date not greater than today:

```
select c.price
from cost c
where c.id = 'Item1'
and c.fromdate = (
  select max(fromdate) from cost
  where id = c.id and fromdate <= getdate() 
)
```

Or:

```
select top 1 price
from cost
where id = 'Item1' and fromdate <= getdate()
order by fromdate desc
```

To create a todate column:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by fromdate) rn
  from cost
)
select c.id, c.price, c.fromdate, dateadd(day, -1, cc.fromdate) todate
from cte c left join cte cc
on cc.id = c.id and cc.rn = c.rn + 1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f001ecd0673b16152ddeb5f87dfd4ff2).

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Peter Schneider, a sensible option would be to use window function `lead()` to recover the `fromdate` of the next record for the same `id`:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    lead(fromdate) over(partition by id order by fromdate) todate
from mytable t
```

Note that with this technique, the record that has the highest `fromdate` for each `id` will have `todate` set to `null`. If you want to assign a default end date you can use `coalesce()`.

You can put this in a view:

```
create view myview as
select 
    t.*, 
    lead(fromdate) over(partition by id order by fromdate) todate
from mytable t
```

And then you can query the view for the current price of a given item:

```
select *
from myview
where 
    id = ? 
    and getdate() >= fromdate
    and (todate is null or getdate() < todate)
```